# Generate nested array using node JS and database (mysql / mongoDB), using recursion

Tags: node.js

I am trying to generate nested array using nodeJS. I tried with mongoDB and MYSQL as well.

My database structure:

parent_id | left_id | right_id

[image]

I tried to do this in PHP and it worked. I write same logic in nodeJS and it is not working. My guess is that is is not working because nodeJS asynchronous.

Code:

```
function testRecX(parent_id, callback) {
    let xyz = {};

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE parent_id = ' + parent_id, function (err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) throw err

        xyz.parent = parent_id;

        if(rows[0].left_id) {
            console.log(" -- LEFT -- " + rows[0].left_id);
            xyz.left = testRecX(rows[0].left_id, null);
        }

        if(rows[0].right_id) {
            console.log(" -- RIGHT -- " + rows[0].right_id);
            xyz.right = testRecX(rows[0].right_id, null);
        }

        if(callback == null) {
            console.log(" -- RETURN -- " + xyz);
            return xyz;
        }

        else {
            console.log(" -- CALLBACK -- " + xyz);
            return callback(xyz);
        }
    });
}
```

Output I get:

[image]

Output required:

```
{
  parent: 1,
  left: {
    parent: 2,
    left: {
      parent: 4,
      left: {
        parent: 8,
        left: null,
        right: null
      },
      right: null
    },
    right: {
      parent: 5,
      left: null,
      right: null
    }
  },
  right: {
    parent: 3,
    left: {
      parent: 6,
      left: null,
      right: {
        parent: 9,
        left: null,
        right: null
      }
    },
    right: {
      parent: 7,
      left: null,
      right: null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how is the resulting nested array supposed to look like?

Comment: @samuq Please check in question, i have already added it. (at the end of the question)

Comment: What is the initial callback?

Comment: testRecX(1, function(result) { console.log(result);}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works (requires ES8 support available in node.js 7.6 and above):

```
async function testRecX(parent_id, callback) {
    let xyz = {};

    await connection.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE parent_id = ' + parent_id, 
       async function (err, rows, fields) {

         if (err) throw err

         xyz.parent = parent_id;
         xyz.left = await (rows[0].left_id?testRecX(rows[0].left_id, null):null)
         xyz.right = await (rows[0].right_id?testRecX(rows[0].right_id, null):null)

         return callback?(console.log(" -- CALLBACK -- " + xyz), callback(xyz)):(console.log(" -- RETURN -- " + xyz),xyz);

    });
}
const results= testRecX(callback).then(data=>console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Node.js is non render blocking. It will not wait for the `SELECT` query to be completed.
So, for I/O operations, use promise. Your code should become :

```
function testRecX(parent_id, callback) {
    let xyz = {};

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE parent_id = ' + parent_id,
    function (err, rows, fields).then(rows=>{
     //your other code here
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it is covering only the first generation tree.
And only console inside the function is showing the data.

const results = testRecX(user[0].user_id,function(data){console.log(data)});

results shows the empty array.

```js
function testRecX(parent_id, callback) {
  let xyz = {};
    
     Referral.find({parent_id:parent_id})
    .then( (err, rows, fields) => {

        if (err) throw err
           
         console.log(rows);

         xyz.parent = parent_id;
          
          xyz.left = (rows[0].left ? testRecX(rows[0].left, null):null);
          xyz.right = (rows[0].right ? testRecX(rows[0].right, null):null);           
        
         return callback ? (console.log(" -- CALLBACK -- " + xyz), callback(xyz)):(console.log(" -- RETURN -- " + xyz),xyz);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

}
```

[tree image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjhci.png)